# Rewrite the pagename in the footer of the browser using Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net

I have used URL Rewrite in Asp.Net webform. So my browser address bar shows the page as **webform1** instead of **webform1.aspx**.

However, I have an Asp.Net Button control which postbacks to the same page. When I place the mouse cursor on top of the Button control, the browser footer still shows the page name as **WebForm1.aspx**.

[image]

Is there a way I can show this as **webform1** isntead of **WebForm1.aspx**?

Comment: which browser are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the form action to the rewritten URL after the page has loaded using Request.RawUrl

So something like this -

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
     form1.Action = Request.RawUrl;  
}
```

This article explains it better http://ruslany.net/2008/10/aspnet-postbacks-and-url-rewriting/